# Implementation difference when using std::find on a std::map between libc++ and libstdc++

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++, libc++

I am trying to summarise to some colleagues how `std::find` works, and I wanted to show them how tricky can be to use it on a `std::map` (and why they shouldn't), so I started fiddling on compiler explorer.

I think I run into a implementation discrepancy between `libc++` and `libstdc++`, since the following snippet compiles on the former

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main (){
  std::map<std::string, int> myMap;

  myMap["string1"] = 100;

  std::map<std::string, int>::value_type element("string1", 100);

  auto it = std::find(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), element);
}
```

but fails to compile with the latter generating the following error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'find'
  auto it = std::find(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), element);
            ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:373:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'istreambuf_iterator' against '_Rb_tree_iterator'
    find(istreambuf_iterator<_CharT> __first,
    ^
1 error generated.
```

So I am puzzled and I wonder which of the two is the desired behaviour. Compiler Explorer links:

- with libc++ https://godbolt.org/z/KDsMsC
- with libstdc++ https://godbolt.org/z/g3DqlJ

Comment: You have to include the header <algorithm>, So what is the problem?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I guess the only problem is the compiler error appears to suggest argument mismatch "could not match 'istreambuf_iterator' against '_Rb_tree_iterator'"

Comment: @SPD The compiler explicitly says that the name std::find is not found.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I know. I'm only stating the fact that template errors are often quite confusing, and this is a good example. In this case, it'd be much better for compiler just to suppress "could not match 'istreambuf_iterator' ..." line -- this would be much more intuitive and most likely we won't spend time on this post at all.

Comment: @SPD At first the compiler did not find the function. After the function will be found the compiler can say whether its arguments are valid.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow can you tell me whether the compiler found the function or not? And where "istreambuf_iterator" is coming from?

Comment: @SPD See the compoler message in the question. The only function find that is found by the compiler is find(istreambuf_iterator<_CharT> __first,

Comment: @VladfromMoscow exactly, that's what threw me off. I didn't think about the missing header because at first I was more confused by where the `istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>` was coming from.
However this is an issue that I find myself running into routinely when working with both implementation of the STL, eventually I'll just learn...

Comment: @VladfromMoscow where did the compiler find "find(istreambuf_iterator<_CharT> __" from?  What's the relationship between "find(istreambuf_iterator<_CharT> __"  and "std::find"? Naturally someone who reads such message would ask such question.

Comment: @SPD As it is followed from the message the function is declared in streambuf_iterator.h

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Sure, I know there must be a "find(istreambuf_iterator)" defined somewhere :) The point is, the user has a clear intention to use std::find (which has a clearly defined interface), but the compiler suggests a library defined specialization "find(istreambuf_iterator)" doesn't match the argument -- that's not what the user is asking for! It'd be better for the compiler to be intelligent enough to tell "std::find() is not found directly" or to be more verbose to say "I cann't find the main template std::find, but I found specialization in xxx.h, however it doesn't match argument"

Comment: @VladfromMoscow <rant>C++ is on the decline.. In my view, things like this has played a significant role -- they made C++ a much harder language than how it could be ...<rant over>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must `#include <algorithm>`, as documented [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

You're just getting (un)lucky that one library implicitly included that header for you, but you really shouldn't depend on it.

Comment: Why an standard std class like `std::string` or `std::map` should be dependant on algorithms to `#include` its headet file? any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the string implementation decides to use std::find in one of its methods. It's an implementation detail, don't worry about it, and don't depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you look through the C++ Standard when you will see that the only header that the C++ Standard requires to be included when the header `<map>` is used is the header `<initializer_list>`. The same is valid for the header `<string>`. That is the only required included header is `<initializer_list>`.

Implementations are allowed to include any other headers in `<map>` and `<string>`. However it is implementation defined.

A similar situation takes place for example with the header `<string>` when the header `<iostream>` is used. Some implementations include the header `<string>` in the header `<iostream>` others do not do this.

So you always should include all required headers if the Standard does not explicitly specify that these headers are included in other used headers.

Comment: [\[res.on.headers\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/res.on.headers#1) says "A C++ header *may* include other C++ headers."  Is that actually impl def?

Comment: @L.F. Yes, it is implementation defined. It depends on an implementation what headers will be included.

Comment: How did you get to that conclusion?  *may* != implementation defined.  It can also be unspecified behavior.  In particular, [Index of implementation-defined behavior](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/impldefindex) doesn't list it.

Comment: @L.F. May means implementation defined because it is not specified what exact headers an implementation will include.

Comment: [\[defns.impl.defined\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/defns.impl.defined) says "that depends on the implementation and that *each implementation documents*."  In contrast, [\[defns.unspecified\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/defns.unspecified) merely says "that depends on the implementation."

Comment: @L.F. This does not contradict that it is implementation defined. All implementation defined features are described in the implementation documentation. So your comments do not make any sense.

Comment: Well, if my comments do not make any sense, show me where the standard requires that each implementation documents what headers are included in `<map>`.  That's a part of the definition of "implementation defined behavior."

Comment: @L.F. You already pointed a quote that a C++ header may include other headers.

Comment: Yes, but it does not say that each implementation documents what headers are included in <map>.  How does it help?

Comment: @L.F. Do you mean the human words "implementation defined"?  Otherwise who does thsi? You yourself?

Comment: ???  I am trying to argue that this is *unspecified behavior* instead of *implementation-defined behavior*.  (Not that this distinction is relevant to non-pedantic people ;-)

Comment: @L.F. the behavior is specified: an implementation may include other headers.

Comment: That's right. Therefore, the behavior is unspecified: `<map>` does or does not include `<initializer_list>`.